# Android NFC error callback

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

My android app can use an empty NFC tag (received directly from manufacturer). On the first use, the tag is written with a NDEF content.

When scan a tag, i need to differentiate 3 situations :

1) a empty tag, default from manufacturer (no content)

2) a NDEF tag, with content `text/plain`.

3) the same NDEF tag, BUT with a scan error.

Item 2 is working fine, but i need to differentiate between 1 and 3.

This is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    String recordContent = null;
    if (intent.hasExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG)) {
        Parcelable[] parcelables = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        if (parcelables != null && parcelables.length > 0) {
            NdefRecord[] ndefRecords = ((NdefMessage) parcelables[0]).getRecords();

            NdefRecord ndefRecord = ndefRecords[0];
            byte[] payload = ndefRecord.getPayload();

            if (payload.length > 0) {
                String textEncoding = ((payload[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "UTF-16";
                int languageSize = payload[0] & 0063;
                recordContent = new String(payload, languageSize + 1, payload.length - languageSize - 1, textEncoding);
            }
        }

        // Do something with recordContent
    }
}
```

What i have tried:

1) Verified the `parcelables` var. But it is null in both situations (empty tag and scan error)

2) The action of `intent`, but it is `TAG_DISCOVERED` in both situations too. When tag is read correctly (with NDEF content), the action is `EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES`.

3) Tag UID is always received.

There is a way of detect a scan error?

Comment: Have you checked whether NdefFormatable helps to distinguish case 1 and 3? It might be that a tag with a scan error is not seen as formatable.

Comment: @corvairjo For empty tag (case 1) NdefFormatable is always null. For case 3, sometimes NdefFormatable is null, other contains a formatable tag.

Comment: I'm sorry @corvairjo. NdefFormatable is always an object for case 1. For case 3, sometimes NdefFormatable is null, other contains a formatable tag.